# Sending extra data through ajax using Rails 3 :remote and jquery

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I want to send extra data using link_to with remote: true

---

It seems to me there are a fair number of tutorials providing guidance for using jQuery in Rails 3. Unfortunately, the majority seem to be repeats of each other or simply do not help me in the area I need.

I am currently implementing a newsfeed style sidebar in my Rails application. When the user first loads the webpage, let's say 10 items are showing. There is an option to "load more items" at the bottom of the newsfeed.

Up to this point, I have simply used a script tag and generated all the html by hand rather than using existing partials. I am trying to get away from this.

To know how many new items are already being displayed I have been using jQuery to count the number of news items on the page (so when I query the database, I can offset by that many records) and sending that as the `data` attribute of the AJAX request.

I am moving towards something  alongs the lines of:

```
<%= link_to "Load More Items", url_for(:action => 'load_wb'), remote: true %>
```

However, I cannot seem to pass any additional information.

Is there a way to change the data in (possibly in the `ajax:before` event?) so I can still make use of jQuery to count the number of existing data items?

In a more general case which may be applicable to others, how can one pass data at all through a helper such as link_to?

I also tried

```
 <%= link_to "Load More Items", url_for(:action => 'load_wb'), remote: true, current_count: 5 %>
```

and still had no success

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to "Load More Items", 
url_for({action: "load_wb", current_count: 5}), 
remote: true %>
```